# Why can't I display an edit form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nomethoderror

I've created an app where a user has_one profile and a profile belongs_to a user. 
It's set up so the profile is automatically created when a user is created (in the user controller)

I am not trying to set it up so a user can visit an edit page (profile controller -> edit action) and edit their profile information through a rendered form (using a _form partial)

I cannot work out why I can't get the edit form to display, as far as I can tell the method is defined correctly?. Anyone got any ideas why? Greatly appreciate any help!

**Browser:**

```
NoMethodError in ProfilesController#edit
undefined method `user' for nil:NilClass    

  def edit
    @profile = @profile.user
  end

  def destroy
```

**Profile Controller:**

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user,  only: [:edit, :destroy]

  def edit
    @profile = @profile.user
  end

  def destroy
  end
end
```

**User Controller**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user,  only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :correct_user,    only: [:edit, :update]

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      @user.profile = Profile.new
      @user.send_activation_email
      flash[:info] = "Please check your email to activate your account."
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

...
```

**views/profiles/edit.html.erb**

```
<% provide(:title, 'Edit Profile') %>
<h1>Editing profile</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for(@profile) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'form', f: f %>
      <%= f.submit "Edit Information", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

**views/profiles/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

<%= f.label :first_name %>
<%= f.text_field :first_name, class: 'form-control' %>

...
```

Comment: are you using devise to handle user authentication? if you are ( and IMHO you should) you should possibly be using @profile = current_user.profile, with your current setup i might be able to edit any users profile just by changing the id in the url

Comment: Thanks! that did it! It's such an obvious answer! I've been coding all day so I think my brains just starting to melt. I built my own authentication so I could better understand how everything works- I didn't like devise because I couldn't see their controllers and didn't like inheriting without understanding what was happening.

Comment: I can accept you answer if you post it as one? Are you saying I should use devise because I haven't built it enough that to block against someone potentially editing a profile by changing the url?

Comment: I dont know what your authentication system looks like or what measures you have in place, with devise everything is customisable, you can see all the controllers in the docs, if you want to change something then its quite simple, there are lots of docs and in my experience its built to be safe and comes with a lot of pre built methods to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what your authentication system looks like, though you mentioned you looked at devise and built your own, so I think you need to do something like this in your edit action

```
  def edit
    @profile = current_user.profile
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to acces to user'profile and not to profile'users, try this in ProfilesController.

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user,  only: [:edit, :destroy]

  def edit
    @profile = current_user.profile
  end

  def destroy
  end
end
```

Comment: I tried that first and it had the same problem - which is why i tried switching it

Comment: Are u logged using the devise gem? if yes then you have access to the current_user